# Query create a column from totalling sum by day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has the columns "Animal ID" "Animal Date" "Viper Date" "Total_Volume" and "Type of specific frog". I need to get a composition % by day so what I need to do is sum the "Total_Volume" by "Animal Date" and then divide it by individual "Total Volume" so I can get the composition % by day.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions.  The following calculates the ratio for each animal based on the total for that animal on that day:

```
select t.*,
       (t.total_volume /
        sum(t.total_volume) over (partition by animalId, cast(animalDate as date))
       ) as day_ratio
from t;
```

I would suggest that you do the formatting at the application layer.

Comment: I get the following message "Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered."